# Automount CIFS / SMB that gracefully handles a non responding server

Tags: mount, 17.10, fstab, automount, cifs

There are lots of pages that show how to configure the system to automatically mount a network share accessed by CIFS (`fstab`, `autofs`, `systemd.mount`, probably even more). But they fail (at least my trials with the first two) when the server is not responding. With the update to Kubuntu 17.10 it even makes my system hang on boot with a black screen and syslog filled with:

```
CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -113
```

And some:

```
CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -111
```

So what is the recommended way to handle such a set up?

- Mount a CIFS share at a given mount point (a KDE `smb://` isn't enough)
- Do everything automatically for every user
- Take care that no problems occur when the target isn't available
- When the target becomes available just mount it

Background: the target is my NAS that goes to sleep and wakes up on network traffic. So at least for the first requests it won't be available.
And when the notebook would be booted in a foreign network the NAS wouldn't even be available at all (or I start a VPN connection)

Answer (score 2):

I think you can solve this problem using `systemd.mount` and `systemd.automount`. This will create a mountpoint that's implemented on-demand and not hang your system during boot.

Per the manpage for [systemd.mount(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/systemd.mount.5.html):

> Optionally, a mount unit may be accompanied by an automount unit,
> to allow on-demand or parallelized mounting. See
> systemd.automount(5).

And from the manpage for [systemd.automount(5)](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/systemd.automount.5.html):

> A unit configuration file whose name ends in ".automount" encodes
> information about a file system automount point controlled and
> supervised by systemd. Automount units may be used to implement
> on-demand mounting as well as parallelized mounting of file
> systems.

In order to do this, you have to create a `systemd.mount` unit file as well as a `systemd.automount` unit file.

---

## Create moutpoint

First, create a directory for your CIFS network share to mount to:

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/share
```

## Create `systemd.mount` unit file

Next, create a `systemd.mount` unit file in `/etc/systemd/system/`. The filename must contain the mountpoint name with the slashes replaced with the “minus” symbol. For example, for the mountpoint created above, `/mnt/share`, create a unit file named, `mnt-share.mount`. See [systemd.mount(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/systemd.mount.5.html):

> ```
>    Mount units must be named after the mount point directories they
>    control. Example: the mount point /home/lennart must be
>    configured in a unit file home-lennart.mount. For details about
>    the escaping logic used to convert a file system path to a unit
>    name, see systemd.unit(5). Note that mount units cannot be
>    templated, nor is possible to add multiple names to a mount unit
>    by creating symlinks to its unit file.
> ```

For this file, you'll need the following info:

- IP address and directory of your NAS server
- YourCIFSUserName
- YourPassword
- YourDomain

Add the following to `/etc/systemd/system/mnt-share.mount`, substituting the above values:

```
[Unit]
  Description=cifs mount unit
  Requires=network-online.target
  After=network-online.service

[Mount]
  What=//NAS-IP-Address/directory
  Where=/mnt/share
  Options=username=YourCIFSUserName,password=YourPassword,workgroup=YourDomain,rw
  Type=cifs

[Install]
  WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**Do not enable the above unit.** If you do, it'll attempt to mount your network share during each boot and hang your system as before.

## Create `systemd.automount` unit file

Next, create a `systemd.automount` unit: `/etc/systemd/system/mnt-share.automount`. This `systemd.automount` unit will start the `mnt-share.mount` unit on demand.

```
[Unit]
  Description=cifs automount unit

[Automount]
  Where=/mnt/share

[Install]
  WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**Enable and start this unit:**

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl enable mnt-share.automount
sudo systemctl start mnt-share.automount
```

---

After starting this unit, the sharepoint will not be mounted yet, but the `/etc/mtab` file will have been updated with a new entry. You can see this with:

```
$ mount | grep share
systemd-1 on /mnt/share type autofs (...)
```

Finally, browse to the network share, where it should be automounted and list the directory contents:

```
ls /mnt/share
```

You can also check the mount:

```
$ mount | grep share
systemd-1 on /mnt/share type autofs (...)
//NAS-IP-Address/directory on /mnt/share type ext4 (rw,relatime)
```

Answer (score 0):

Install

```
sudo apt-get install cifs-utils
```

if not already done.

As sudo user add one or more entries into your `/etc/fstab`

```
//YourSambaServer/folder /mnt/share/ cifs username=YourCIFSUserName, password=YourPassword,noauto,_netdev,users 0 0
```

To explain:

1. The first entry shows the samba location of your SMB Server, plus
   the folder you want to mount
2. Then the mount point on your local device - it doesn't have to be
   /mnt/..,  any local folder will work
3. Your samba credentials
4. The flags you will need to mount the share or ignore it if not
   present

Reboot and you should be ready to go

I'm using this solution for years with the benefit of getting higher transfer rates via cifs. Note, that with these settings you can mount your samba folders any time.